# How prove that the square root operator commutes with every operator $X$ that commutes with its square

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

Let $U ∈ \mathcal{L}(H)$ be such that $U^* = U$ and $U ≥ 0$ (i.e $(Ux,x)\geq0$), exists $V ∈ \mathcal{L}(H )$ such that $V^*  = V$, $V \geq 0$, and $V^2 = U$. The operator
$V$ is called the square root of $U$. How prove that the operator $V$ commutes with every operator $X$
that commutes with $U$ (i.e., $X \circ U = U \circ X$ implies $X \circ V = V \circ X$)?
I really have no idea what to do, can someone give a tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The continuous functional calculus gives a continuous homomorphism $\varphi:C(X)\to\mathcal{L}(H)$ where $X$ is the spectrum of $U$ and $\varphi(f)=U$ where $f(x)=x$ is the identity function.  The operator $V$ is then just $\varphi(g)$ where $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is the square root function.  By the Weierstrass approximation theorem, $g$ is a limit of polynomials in $f$, and so applying $\varphi$ we see that $V$ is a limit of polynomials in $U$.  Any operator which commutes with $U$ commutes with any polynomial in $U$, and thus taking limits also commutes with $V$.

Comment: I didn't know this result about this continuous homomorphism you can refer me to a book where i can find more details on the subject?